# Не работает routing

Tags: symfony, маршрутизация, twig, sonata

Имеется форма:

```
<form action="{{ path('talon_ticket_send_email', {'slugTicket': messages[0].id}) }}">
    <textarea class="form-control block-answer"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Ответить</button>
</form>
```

При клике на кнопку, должен выполняться переход на другую страницу, для этого в файле `/src/Talon/TicketBundle/Resource/config/routing.yml` имеется код:

```
talon_ticket_send_email:
path:     /admin/talon/ticket/ticket/{slugTicket}/sendemail
defaults: { _controller: TalonTicketBundle:Ticket:sendEmail}
```

Но при клике на кнопку выскакивает странная ошибка `There is no _sonata_admin defined for the controller Talon\TicketBundle\Controller\TicketController and the current route talon_ticket_send_email`, чем лечить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что контроллер наследовался от CRUDController, а нужно было от Controller